# How to print multiple page ranges with WPF PrintDialog

Tags: wpf, printing

I used following codes to print a visual to a printer, the page range is from 1 to 3;

Code snippets:

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.PrintQueue = CurrentPrinter;
printDialog.PrintTicket = CurrentPrinter.UserPrintTicket;
printDialog.PageRangeSelection = PageRangeSelection.UserPages;
printDialog.UserPageRangeEnabled = true;
printDialog.PageRange = new PageRange(1, 3);
if((bool)printDialog.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
    printDialog.PrintDocument(Paginator, "");
```

Currently I need to print multiple page ranges, for example, 1-3,5-7. But WPF print dialog only support one page range, is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance.